# In Age of the Five, what are the names of the Gods?

Tags: names, trudi-canavan, age-of-five

In Age of the Five, by Trudi Canavan there Circlians have 5 gods.
What are their names?

The Pentadrians also have 5 Gods,
what are their names?

The names of the Gods are not in the glossary, and are only mentioned all together a few times in the books. 
On the Circlian side, I know one is Huan, who is mentioned alot, and another is Chaia.
But the Pentadrian names are only mentioned like once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The names of the **[Circlian](http://canavansbooks.wikia.com/wiki/Circlian_Gods)** gods are:

- Chaia
- Huan
- Lore
- Yranna
- Saru

The names of the **[Pentadrian](http://canavansbooks.wikia.com/wiki/Pentadrian_gods)** gods are:

- Sheyr
- Ranah
- Alor
- Sraal
- Hrun